# Как ускорить записать данных из списка в строку? Kotlin

Tags: алгоритм, kotlin, оптимизация

выполняя работу столкнулся с проблемой. Мне необходимо решить систему оду методом рунге-кутта 4 порядка. Необходимо использовать большое количество узлов, но уже на 100 000 сталкиваюсь с проблемой.
Суть проблемы в том, что решение строится быстро, примерно 3 сек, но потом данное решение мне необходимо записать в файл. Для этого я занашу данные в строку и потом просто создаю файл с этой строкой внутри. Но если решение ищется за 3 секунды, то записаь данных в строки происходит примерно 30 мин.

```
for (i in 0..valu.lastIndex) {
    textEx4123 += "${valu[i][0]} ${valu[i][1]} ${valu[i][2]}  \n"
    textEx4234 += "${valu[i][1]} ${valu[i][2]} ${valu[i][3]}  \n"
    textEx4341 += "${valu[i][2]} ${valu[i][3]} ${valu[i][0]}  \n"
    textEx4412 += "${valu[i][3]} ${valu[i][0]} ${valu[i][1]}  \n"
    textEx412 += "${valu[i][0]} ${valu[i][1]}  \n"
    textEx413 += "${valu[i][0]} ${valu[i][2]}  \n"
    textEx414 += "${valu[i][0]} ${valu[i][3]}  \n"
    textEx423 += "${valu[i][1]} ${valu[i][2]}  \n"
    textEx424 += "${valu[i][1]} ${valu[i][3]}  \n"
    textEx434 += "${valu[i][2]} ${valu[i][3]}  \n"
    textEx4t1 += "${x[i]} ${valu[i][0]}  \n"
    textEx4t2 += "${x[i]} ${valu[i][1]}  \n"
    textEx4t3 += "${x[i]} ${valu[i][2]}  \n"
    textEx4t4 += "${x[i]} ${valu[i][3]}  \n"
    println(i)
}
```

Вот код цикла, в котором я заношу данные. valu это список решений. Он является списком списков так как я решаю систему, но не в этом суть.

Как я могу ускорить процесс записи данных в строки чтобы потом записать их в файл? или есть другой подход?

P.S. Просто запись списка в файл мне не подходит, так как мне нужны данные именно в таком формате, чтобы потом рисовать 2D или 3D графики.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `StringBuilder`. Строки неизменяемы, у Вас при каждом сложении старая строка копируется (а она охренеть какая здоровенная должна быть)

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно быстро нашел ответ, после того как задал вопрос, но искал я ответ до вопроса достаточно долго.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]